# show all tags on focus bootstrap taginput js

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using [bootstrap tags input js](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

This is my code

```
var question_tags =  new Bloodhound({
          local: catItem,
          queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
          datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('text')
        });
        question_tags.initialize();

        var elt = $('#question_tags');
        elt.tagsinput({
            allowDuplicates: false,
            itemValue: 'value',
            itemText: 'text',
          typeaheadjs:{
            name: 'question_tags',
            displayKey: 'text',
            source: question_tags.ttAdapter()
          }
        });
```

This is working fine when I start typing, it shows me results related to typed string.

But I want all my auto-suggestions to show as soon as I focus on input box.I can't see any option on it's document page for focus results.

Does anybody know how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For your need purpose, I think you need a dropdown with searching feature. So, I suggest you using select2 plugin.

Check this link:
https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: yes I need this functionality but isnt it possible with bootstrap tag js. I have already used it.